# Installing sparkR on windows

Tags: r, windows, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a problem with the installation of Apache sparkR. To install this type of program you have to use the command prompt and "run" (for me) sparkR as requested here:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio/

However, by running the following command line I found a path issue. (I checked registry problems and purposely make a short path without long words). :

```
PS C:\Users\Maxime> cd ..
PS C:\Users> cd ..
PS C:\> cd .\Apache\
PS C:\Apache> cd .\spark\
PS C:\Apache\spark> .\bin\sparkR
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable. // Translate: The specified path was not found.
PS C:\Apache\spark>
```

What should I do to work? (i would like to stay on windows)

Thank you very much !

Comment: More information required.

Answer (score 0):

the r-bloggers article that you quote installs Spark in a different folder to the one that you are in.  It uses the directory c:\Apache\Spark-1.4.1 , whereas you are in c:\Apache\spark.

It seems that you are unfamiliar with using the command prompt to locate an installation.  If you don't know your way around the command line then you will struggle with Spark.  It requires a lot of configuration so you really need to be comfortable with paths, directories etc.  You can try a tutorial like [this one](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html)

If you are trying to learn Spark, you can avoid the trouble of maintaining an installation by signing up for a (free) hosted Spark account here:[Databricks.com community edition](https://databricks.com/try-databricks).  You also get a lot of help and training materials with that account.